# Growth conditions for partial differential equations

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, motivation

Hi I am interested in what the exact purpose is of growth conditions associated with solving partial differential equations. For example the following pde:
$$\text{div}(a(x,u,\nabla u)) + c(c,u,\nabla u) = g$$ 
where examples of some of the growth conditions associated with it are 
$$|a(x,r,s)| \leq \gamma(x) + C|r|^{\frac{(p^{*}-\epsilon)}{p'}} + C|s|^{p-1}$$ and

$$|c(x,r,s)| \leq \gamma(x) + C|r|^{p^{*}-\epsilon -1} + C|s|^{\frac{p}{p^{*'}}}$$

Can someone with some knowledge of pde's give me an idea of why growth conditions are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The PDE of this form is typically posed in some Sobolev space $W^{1,p}$. At a minimum, we need  the weak formulation 
$$\int (-a(x,u,\nabla u)\nabla \phi + c(x,u,\nabla u) \phi - g\phi)=0 \tag{1}$$ 
to make sense for $\phi\in C^\infty_0$. But often, to actually use $(1)$ one needs $\phi$ to be somehow based on $u$. So we'd like to allow $\phi$ in a Sobolev space too, probably the same $W^{1,p}$.  Then $(1)$ requires $ a(x,u,\nabla u)\in L^{p'}$ and $c(c,u,\nabla u)\in L^{(p^*)'}$.  Since $u\in L^{p^*}$ and $\nabla u\in L^p$, we need $a=O(|u|^{p^*/p'})$ and  $a=O(|\nabla u|^{p/p'})$ (where $p/p'=p-1$) and so forth. That some $\epsilon$ appears in the exponents probably has to do with the specific method employed by the authors of the paper you are reading. But the above gives the general idea of what motivates those assumptions.

Comment: By "make sense" and "use (1)" do you mean that we need conditions on $a$ and $c$ such that the integral in (1) is summable?

Comment: Yes, it should converge.

Comment: @Behaviour Thanks for your response. Do you know why it is that the applications of monotone and pseudomonotone operators to proving the existence of a weak solution tend to be applied specifically to 'quasilinear elliptic' boundary value problems?